# Index of a point on a Jordan curve

Tags: general-topology

Let $p$ be a point on a Jordan curve $J$.
Let $\gamma$ be a loop in the bounded component of $\mathbb{C} \backslash J$.
Show that $ind(\gamma,p) = 0$.
Can we just tell that the curve is contractible to a point, and then that the index of a point relative to point equals $0$?

Comment: It's not quite obvious, although it is true, that such a curve is contractible (see the Schoenflies theorem in dimension 2). This implies the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jordan–Schoenflies theorem says that $\mathbb C \setminus J$ has two components, one bounded and one unbounded, and that the bounded component $B$ is homeomorphic to an open disk. Hence $\gamma$ is homotopic in $B \subset \mathbb C \setminus \{ p \}$ to a constant loop. If you know that the index is homotopy invariant, then you are in fact done.